# Comments that show you output from your methods

Tags: editor, textmate

I saw [a video](https://vimeo.com/24716767) yesterday in which a guy wrote a Ruby method in his text editor and then got the output in a comment. It looked like this:

```
def method(args)
  #*do stuff*
end

method(args) # => *method output*
```

The method output looked like it was just automatically generated. This seems like a very convenient feature. How can I do that?

Comment: it would help if you give us the url of the video

Comment: TextMate has such feature. "Bundles -> Ruby -> Execute and Update '# =>' Markers."

Comment: There's plugin for this in SublimeText too, IIRC

Comment: @SergioTulentsev please add that to the answer currently posted... It will help make it more thorougj

Comment: This really doesn't have much to do with Ruby, it's a feature of the editor / IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the editor, you can use [Ruby Markers](https://github.com/mmims/sublime-text-2-ruby-markers) or [Seeing is Believing](https://github.com/JoshCheek/seeing_is_believing). They build upon xmpfilter and [rcodetools](https://github.com/JoshCheek/rcodetools).

Sublime, vim and Textmate all support them in one form or another. You'll need to read their directions to find out how to install them in the particular environment.

Seeing Is Believing is the most powerful and trouble-free in my experience. [The video](http://vimeo.com/73866851) is impressive.

This is from Sublime using Ruby Markers:

```
bar = [1,2] # => [1, 2]
bar.reverse # => [2, 1]
bar << 3 # => [1, 2, 3]
bar.shift # => 1

'foo'[/f(.)/] # => "fo"
'foo'[/f(.)/, 1] # => "o"
```

This is from Sublime 2 using "Seeing Is Believing":

```
bar = [1,2] # => [1, 2]
bar.map{ |i| 
  i.to_s # => "1", "2"
} # => ["1", "2"]
```

Trying to do the same thing in Ruby Markers results in:

```
bar = [1,2] # => 
bar.map{ |i| 
  i.to_s # => 
} # => 
# ~> -:4: syntax error, unexpected '}'
# ~> ...439400863_68853_278261 = (    });$stderr.puts("!XMP143940086...
# ~> ...                               ^
# ~> -:4: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'
```

Seeing Is Believing doesn't work with Sublime 3 yet. Sublime 3 is in beta still, so making Seeing... compatible is probably waiting for the full release. Ruby Markers doesn't handle blocks written across multiple lines well, so there are tradeoffs to either.

Answer (score 0):

That's a feature that's built in to TextMate, which seems to be what they're using in the video.